# What are applicable scenarios in using HTTP status 207 in REST API?

Tags: web-services, rest

Planning to use http status 207/ multi status as a response for updating/deleting list of objects in a REST api. I plan to respond with 204 if all succeeds and 207 if it's a mixture of successes/failures.

Is this the right usage for 207?

What scenarios does http 207 commonly used on?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you perform a destructive operation like POST, PUT, DELETE against more than one resource and the operations against each individual resource did not share a common outcome then you can go for 207.

For example,

- If you DELETEd two resources and both were deleted you can expect

  200. 
- If both DELETEs were forbidden, you'd expect 403.
- If one DELETE was successful but one was forbidden, you would receive 207.

Some more [discussion](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/w3c-dist-auth/1999JanMar/0128.html) on 207 status.

Comment: i would say if you have a batched request like that you should just fail the entire request and not apply the transaction on your database

Comment: That assumes you have control over the backend system/database.  You may be calling another API (for example) that accepts some records and rejects others.  207 seems like a useful response in this instance, except for it being non-standard.

Answer (score 3):

The question is a bit old, but as it is one the best result about the use of `207 Multi-status` in REST API, I would suggest another scenario.

I normally use the `207` in CRUD operations that triggers some long running task, too.

*E.g.:* an API for an insert operation that triggers a long recalculation will reply a 207 status, with all the information about the entity inserted (`201 Created` + DTO) and the long running task (`202 Accepted` + task token). This approach fits well even when the reply should be without body (`204 No content` in update or delete requests).